# C# WPF - Adorner ZIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, adorner

I have a Grid with a Adorner to provide some drawn pattern. See img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUJmh.jpg

My problem is that this Adorner(dots on the Grid) is layered on top of everything. The white square are draggable but now when the Adorner are on top, I can't drag. I would like the layer to be behind every component added to the Grid. Any suggestions on how I can set the ZIndex?

Thanks.

Code below:

```
  MyAdorner ad = new MyAdorner(grid);
  AdornerLayer adLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(grid);
  adLayer.Add(ad);
```

I push my Button and this is adding the MyAdorner to the grid. MyAdorner looks like this:

```
public MyAdorner(Grid adornedGrid)
: base(adornedGrid) {
Height = adornedGrid.Height;
Width = adornedGrid.Width;
brush = new VisualBrush();
brush.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
brush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
brush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, SnapDistance, SnapDistance);
brush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
brush.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 0, SnapDistance, SnapDistance);
brush.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
ellipse = new Ellipse() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), Width = 2, Height = 2 };
brush.Visual = ellipse;
}

protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext) { 
Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 0); 
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, renderPen, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), AdornedElement.DesiredSize)); 
}
```

Comment: It's quite alot of code, what part do you need to know?

Comment: The simplest code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Have you defined the Adorner to have the highest Z-Index so that the dots are always on top of the other colours/controls? Also whate vent are you using when trying to Drag? Is it PreviewMouseDown or Mousedown?

Comment: I have not set any Z-Index on the Adorner. Its MouseLeftButtonDown on the square(that is a Grid).

Comment: Try it with PreviewLeftButtonMouseDown and see if the event fires, also to set the Z-Index all you should need to do is call SetZIndex(int index) method on the objects you want to bring forward.

Comment: I tried to do that on a Button: 

    b.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 20);

but still, Adorner are on top.

Comment: Disable hit test for adorner only give hit test to adorner buttons and manage mouse events on adorned element, you can call the adorned element inside the adorner control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Panel.SetZIndex(ad, 20)
```

Attached properties of the framework are usually asignable from static methods of the UIElement that holds it.

**EDIT:**
Possible alternative: - [make your own Panel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF)

Comment: Don't understand where to put this. Enlighten me! :)

Comment: MyAdorner ad = new MyAdorner(grid);
I'd start by trying right after that =)

Comment: Still same result. Adorner on top of everything.

Comment: Well I'm not much surprised, it is the point of an adorner to be on top of the UIElements. You could keep trying but you will end up with something messy. Maybe you should try to find another solution. I'll add ideas to my answer.

Comment: Seems logical enough, I have to go for another approach as your suggestion. I mark this as answered by you.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is that the adorner is covering the elements you want to manipulate so that they become un-draggable etc, set `.IsHitTestVisible = False` on the adorner.

You can also set the adorner's opacity to some semi-transparent value to see the background through it if that is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and dirty way to make sure that your wanted elements are ALWAYS on top:

Declare a static in a Util library:

```
      public static int ZIndexCount;
```

Then when you want an element on top you simply do:

```
         SetZIndex(_viewbox, Util.ZIndexCount++);
```

Of course, if your application runs 5 years without being interrupted the ZIndexCount will go back to 0...

It works like a charm in my applications.

Comment: He doesn't want the adorner on top of everything

Comment: SetZIndex(xxx, Util.ZIndexCount) has to be used on the other controls/elements, they will then automatically above the adorner.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but I thought I try anyway:
You can add a new AdornerDecorator to you visual tree hierarchy to render the controls at the right level. By default the root of the tree provides the AdornerDecorator but you can add as many as you want and your the components you add will be rendered in them. For more information - see here

```
  <Grid>
     <AdornerDecorator>
        ...your Adorners render here
     </AdornerDecorator>
 </Grid>
```

https://wangmo.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/relations-between-adorner-adornerlayer-and-adornerdecorator/